# Use Table View as segue button on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I'm building an app on iOS, but I'm still confused about how to use table view as the button that triggers segue to a search modal view like in the screenshot. Do I have to use regular table view cell and then returns custom number of items in section or how?

[image: iOS app example]

Comment: Within the table's didSelectRowAtIndexPath method you call performSegueWithIdentifier, supplying it with the identify of a segue within your storyboard.

Comment: Then, How can I divide the table view into two columns like the image above. on the left says from and on the right says the city that takes the data from previous modal that triggered by segue?

Comment: Your question is not understandable. Your original question was how to trigger a segue *from* a table view, but now your comment is asking how to  arrange and populate data *in* a table view which has has been triggered by a segue. The two questions totally contradict each other and the result is its impossible to know what it is you are actually asking.

Answer (score 1):

First, you wire up a segue from your tableView controller to you modal view controller in your storyboard and provide an identifier for the segue, then you can have your tableView controller conform to UITableViewDelegate protocol and implement `tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` method. Inside the implementation of that method, you call: `performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?)` and pass in the identifier of the segue from your storyboard.

Comment: Then, How can I divide the table view into two columns like the image above. on the left says from and on the right says the city that takes the data from previous modal that triggered by segue?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, can you rephrase the question?

Comment: @chronycles Are you talking about the section headers, like "JUMLAH PENUMPANG"?

Comment: @DanL no, I mean, the label Dari or Menuju.

Comment: @AhmedOnawale okay then, so I have two tables view, one Medan and one Banda Aceh. So I have to write 2 for numberOfRowsInSection?